# how to highlight text along with sound in android

Tags: android, audio

I have a audio file and I want to read this text file with highlight the text.Can I do this.Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please be more precise in your post?. What is "this" text file? You mean some kind of subtitling or karaoke? what have you tried so far? what problem you've had?

Comment: it is a doc file or text file..when I read it it has to read by sound and also highlight this text

Answer (score 0):

You might begin by reading some introductory documentation on the *Text to Speech* the Android class `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech` at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

With this class you may have your app to easily speak from text. You just create an instance of the class, wait for it to complete its initialization, and speak. Something along this, just to get you started.

```
import com.google.tts.TTS;
...
private TTS myTts;
...
myTts = new TTS(this, ttsInitListener, true);
...
private TTS.InitListener ttsInitListener = new TTS.InitListener() {
  public void onInit(int version) {
    myTts.speak("Hello world", 0, null);
  }
};
```

Things will get more complex when you try to change the "Hello world" by the actual text read from your text file while highlighting the text on screen. I leave it as an exercise for you.

Comment: How to highlight along with speech?